MongoDB 4.4 how to update dict with unknown key
Hello i need a way to update documents in mongodb 4.4, when i dont now the exact key path.
In this example i dont know the dict key,
but i know that there is field "name" with value "test1" under the unknown dict key.
What i want is to update for example the dict with the name "test1".
The dot notation seems to be not a option
example.key1.name, because "key1" is not known.
{
    "example": {
        "key1": {
            "name": "test1"
        },
        "key2": {
            "name": "test2"
        }
    }
}


Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another
question. If the answers there do not address your problem, please
edit to explain in detail the parts of your question that are unique.
MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query

I ask for update not for find.

Does this answer your question? MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query

Thank you, but this was not exactly what i needed

I don't know if exists a better option about performance but you can try to use an aggregation update
The idea is transform your dict into an array, map that array and find your desired value to update, and then restore the dict again.
You can use this query where using $objectToArray you get keys as k value and values as v. Check this example to know how is the data at this step.
So you you can't forget about key value, you don't know key1 but it doesn't matter because you can find your desired object in v.name equals to test1.
So you can $map you get that value using $eq. So "$$this.v.name" has to be test1. And replace using $mergeObjects (add more keys into v if it is necessary).
And then the reverse way, you have an array based on k and v so using $arrayToObject you can rebuild the original dict but updated.
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "example": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$example"
            },
            "in": {
              "$cond": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$this.v.name",
                    "your_goal_value"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$mergeObjects": [
                    "$$this",
                    {
                      "v": {
                        "name": "your new value to update"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "$$this"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Example here
